# Nothing is getting written to database

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, ef-database-first

I'm a beginner in ASP.Net. I'm using Entity Framework Database First Method. I need to store data to my MUSIC Database, in the table called LogTable. I have tried many ways. Nothing works. At last I tried this:

**in Login.aspx**

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using MusicShop.Models;

namespace MusicShop.Pages.Accounts
{
public partial class Login : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void btnLogin_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var userStore = new UserStore<IdentityUser>();

        userStore.Context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString =
            ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MUSICConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

        var manager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(userStore);

        var user = manager.Find(txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text);


        if (user != null)
        {
            InsertUserLog();
            var authenticationManager = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
            var userIdentity = manager.CreateIdentity(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

            authenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                IsPersistent = false
            }, userIdentity);


            Response.Redirect("~/Index.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            litStatus.Text = "Invalid username or password";
        }
    }

    private void InsertUserLog()
    {
            LogModel model = new LogModel(); //Add a new model
            var logtable = new LogTable
            {
                IP = Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"].ToString(),
                //You could set a break point to check the value.
                AGENT = Request.ServerVariables["http_user_agent"].ToString(),
                REQM = Request.ServerVariables["request_method"].ToString(),
                SERVER = Request.ServerVariables["server_name"].ToString(),
                PORT = Request.ServerVariables["server_port"].ToString(),
                SW = Request.ServerVariables["server_software"].ToString(),
                DNS = Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_HOST"].ToString()
            };

            //set value
            var error = model.InsertLog(logtable);

            if (error != null) Response.Write(error);

    }
}
}
```

**in LogModel.cs**

```
public string InsertLog(LogTable logTable)
{
    try
    {
        MUSICEntities db = new MUSICEntities();
        db.LogTables.Add(logTable);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return null;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return "Error:" + e;
    }
}
```

No error. But nothing is added to database. Can anyone guide me? Please pardon me, if this is a silly mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably aren't seeing an error because you aren't checking for it.

try outputting the error you are returning.

```
var error = model.InsertLog(logtable);

if(error != null) Response.Write(error);
```

I also noticed you are simply concatenating the Exception instance ...

you probably should say `"Error:" + e.Message` or `"Error:" + e.StackTrace`

Since you seem to be relying on the `ToString()` method of the Exception class .. not sure how much info you'll get out of it.

Comment: @AmruthaAJ Can you post more of the Login.aspx code .. are you sure this code is even running? can you set a breakpoint to be sure it is getting executed.

Comment: the code is running. All other tables except the LogTable are getting filled when user is logging in

Comment: @AmruthaAJ i'm not talking about your entire application .. just this method `InsertUserLog`

Comment: @AmruthaAJ can you show the code that calls this method? without knowing more about the code, it'll be difficult to know whats wrong.

Comment: @AmruthaAJ the page doesn't remain at Login.aspx .. it is redirected to Index.aspx. so there's no way you'll be able to see the error we are outputting. probably comment out the redirect while you are trying to solve this issue and uncomment it after resolving.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that! Error: at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges() at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges() at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges() at MusicShop.Models.LogModel.InsertLog(LogTable logTable) in c:\Users\Amrutha\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\MusicShop\MusicShop\Models\LogModel.cs:line 16

Comment: @AmruthaAJ Glad it helped. :)

Comment: @AmruthaAJ I think the error is from the user agent string .. it may be longer than the field length you have for it. So maybe you could increase the field lenght to `nvarchar(MAX)` or something

Comment: @AmruthaAJ what are the field sizes for the other fields? do they match the value coming in? is there any required field that you aren't providing value for and isn't auto generated by the db?

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LogTable] (
    [ID]     INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [UserID] INT            NOT NULL,
    [IP]     NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [AGENT]  NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [REQM]   NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [SERVER] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [PORT]   NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [SW]     NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [DNS]    NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_LogTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_LogTable_UserInformation1] FOREIGN KEY ([UserID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[UserInformation] ([ID]) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
    );

Comment: @AmruthaAJ the issue is the UserID .. you need to specify it. since you've declared it as NOT NULL.

Comment: @AmruthaAJ it doesn't matter what the relationship is .. you still have to provided it during the insert into the table.

Comment: @AmruthaAJ you can get the id from the user and pass it to the `InsertUserLog`  `InsertUserLog(user.Id)`  be sure to add the int parameter to the method and use the value as part of your insert via EF

Comment: Thanks a lot. :) for your patience. I think this will solve the problem